# Kill a bash process when a specific string is read from stdout

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am using tail to read a logfile as it is updated and wish to exit the loop if grep returns a specific string.  I'm not sure how to exit or kill the process 'programmatically'

Anyone have any great ideas?
Here's some sample script:

```
tail -f /var/log/{system.log,kernel.log} | grep -i "vendor: 0x22b8"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: related https://superuser.com/questions/375223/watch-the-output-of-a-command-until-a-particular-string-is-observed-and-then-e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep` with a maximum count:

```
tail -f /var/log/{system.log,kernel.log} | grep -i "vendor: 0x22b8" -m 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can effectively do it like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/{system.log,kernel.log} | awk '
  {print}
  /vendor: 0x22b8/ {exit}
'
```

The awk command will exit the first time it sees your string.  The tail command will get killed the next time it tries to write to the pipe due to the SIGPIPE mechanism.